# How to enter a single backspace with Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I would like to use `.sendKeys()` to enter text in an input field, and then backspaces one character.  I've tried using the following code with `.sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE)` but it seems like it clears the entire field.

My test:

```
describe('backspace', function() {
    it('types some stuff and backspaces one character', function() {
        element(by.model('invoice.customerName')).sendKeys('Ali Khoda');

        element(by.model('invoice.customerName')).sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE);

        expect(element(by.model('invoice.customerName')).getText()).toBe('Ali Khod');

    });
});
```

The error: `Expected '' to be 'Ali Khod'.`

Is there a way to backspace only a single character?

**UPDATE:**

I've also tried the following since `.sendKeys()` returns a promise by default.

```
describe('backspace', function() {
    it('types some stuff and backspaces one character', function() {
        element(by.model('invoice.customerName')).sendKeys('Ali Khoda').then(function() {

            element(by.model('invoice.customerName')).sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE).then(function() {

                expect(element(by.model('invoice.customerName')).getText()).toBe('Ali Khod');

            });

        });

    });
});
```

The test fails just the same.

Comment: Using sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE) worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround I found was the following:

`expect(element(by.model('invoice.customerName')).getAttribute('value')).toBe('Ali Khod');`

Instead of using `.getText()`, I used `.getAttribute('value')`.

Comment: `.getText()` returns everything between the selected elements start and closing tags: 
`<div>ONLY THIS WILL BE RETURNED</div>`. 
since input is self closing, getText() doesn't return anything. the right way and not just a workaround is using getAttribute('value'), wich returns the inputs value 'Ali Khod'.